# How do I add a new website in IIS 7 using a script?

Tags: iis, scripting

I want to be able to create a new website with a new host header (which I can obviously do [using the IIS Manager](http://support.gearhost.com/KB/a202/how-to-add-a-website-in-iis-7-on-your-windows-2008-server.aspx)) from the command line so that it can be scripted.

Essentially what you can do with [iisweb on IIS 6](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/aee71684-36c0-40e1-b387-a19d2d0509f0.mspx?mfr=true).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use built-in [appcmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772350(WS.10).aspx), like this - using the bindings argument a host header can be specified:

```
appcmd add site /name:contoso /id:2 /physicalPath:c:\contoso /bindings:http/*:80: marketing.contoso.com
```

> The variable name string is the name,
>   and the variable id uint is the
>   unsigned integer that you want to
>   assign to the site. The variables name
>   string and id uint are the only
>   variables that are required when you
>   add a site in Appcmd.exe. The variable
>   bindings string contains information
>   that is used to access the site, and
>   it should be in the form of
>   protocol/IP_address:port:host_header.

Comment: One thing I found handy was adding multiple bindings in a single call. To do so, wrap each binding in quotes and comma-separate them: `appcmd add site /name:contoso /bindings:"http/*:80:","https/*:443:" /physicalPath:C:\contoso`. Otherwise, you have to do a separate call for each: `appcmd set site /site.name:"G4" /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:']`.

Comment: FYI its location is `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe`

Answer (score 0):

[Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee909471%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

```csh
Import-Module WebAdministration 
New-Website -name "[name]" -HostHeader "[www.example.com]" -PhysicalPath "[c:\inetpub\example.com\]"
```

Using Powershell combined with the .NET assembles:

```csh
[Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager]::OpenRemote($WebServer)
```

You can basically control every facet of the web site/web server.